# How to display a custom number of model records

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

In the database, I have 20 model objects, when I enter model page, I show all 10 records. I want to make a field defining how many records display, for example 10 entries. Then the remaining 10 entries will be on 2 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementing the answer [Eyob Tariku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8767328/eyob-tariku).

```
# admin.py

@admin.register(YourModel)
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        info = self.get_model_info()
        custom_urls = [
            path('change-count-displayed/', self.set_count_displayed),
        ]

        return custom_urls + urls

    def set_count_displayed(self, request):
    count = int(request.POST['count'])

    if count > 0:
        self.list_per_page = count
    else:
        # Your error handling

    return HttpResponseRedirect("../")
```

in templates foler I create "count_display_form.html" and "change_list.html"

```
<!-- count_display_form.html -->
<form action="change-count-displayed/" method="post" style="width: 300px; display: inline-block;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class='vIntegerField' type="number" step="1" pattern="\d+" name='count'{{form.count}} style="width: 75px" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Go" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 15px;">
    View on page
</form>
```

In change_list.html i Include form

```
{% include "admin/yourapp/count_display_form.html" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [ModelAdmin.list_per_page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_per_page) option. In your `admin.py` file, define your admin page and add the aforementioned option with your preferred number of instances per page.

```
# yourapp/admin.py

from django import admin
from .models import Product


@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = 10   # To show 10 model instance per page
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks, but is it possible to set the value of the list_per_page on the model page? (custom field)